# Family with five children- probability.

Tags: probability

Problem :
My friends have 5 children. I know, that  they have **at least** three boys and **at least** one girl. What is the probability, that they have four boys?

Let:
$A$- they have **at least** three boys

$B$- they have **at least** one girl

$C$- they have four boys.

I have to calculate $ P( A \bigcap B \bigcap C )$ ?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a problem of conditional probability. This means that instead of calculating $P(A\cap B \cap C)$, you would be calculating $P(C | (A \cap B))$ or the probability of $C$ given $A$ and $B$. You can calculate this by using the conditional probability formula. Let $D = ( A\cap B)$. Then:

$P(C|D) = \frac{P(C \cap D)}{P(D)}$

**Note that this gets difficult because $P(A \cap B)$ are not independent events. If it is not an independent event then you must use $P(A \cap B) = P(A)*P(B|A) = P(B)*P(A|B)$. You can find these with either total probability theorem or complementary counting.

Edit: Typo

Comment: This is the general way to do this, which I realized is probably a lot harder than the problem intended. Since you know that the family has 5 children total and they have at least 3 boys, at least 1 girl then they can either have 3 boys 2 girls or 4 boys 1 girl. Let these two events represent your sample space and let the event that the family has 4 boys 1 girl represent your desired space. I'm not sure if this is correct, but it might be helpful.

Comment: http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/condprob.htm

Comment: Here is some more info!

Comment: Yes. Let $X$ count the boys in the family of 5. Then we seek:  $$\mathsf P(X=4\mid (X\geq 3)\cap (X\leq 4))=\dfrac{\mathsf P(X=4)}{\mathsf P(3\leq X\leq 4)}$$